# Find command not working in shell script

Tags: shell-script, grep, find, hp-ux

I have a to find for list of words in a list of files. Hence I have put the list of words in a file, and using `for` loop trying to read each word in a file and use find command to `grep` for that word in list of found files.

I am using the mentioned flavor of Linux

```
bash-3.1$ uname
HP-UX
```

And below mentioned is my shell script.

```
  #!/bin/sh
PATH="/NO/20171013"
STRING=`/usr/bin/cat /home/test/STAT44_test.txt`
for LINE in ${STRING}
do
  echo "find ${PATH} -type f -name \"*.txt\" -exec grep -w "${LINE}" {} \; 2>/dev/null | /usr/bin/wc -l"
  LINES=`find ${PATH} -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -w "${LINE}" {} \; 2>/dev/null | /usr/bin/wc -l`
  echo "LINES count is ${LINES}"
  if [ ${LINES} -eq 0 ]
  then
        echo "In not found"
#       echo "${LINE} is not found in ${PATH}" >> /home/test/STAT44_not_found.out
  else
        echo "In Found"
#       echo "${LINE} is found in ${PATH}" >> /home/test/STAT44_found.out
  fi
done
```

The find command `find ${PATH} -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -w '${LINE}' {} \; 2>/dev/null` works perfectly in the command prompt, whereas it is not at giving any output, if used in the shell script as mentioned above.

The output of `echo $?` is 0 but the find command doesn't produce any output.

The output of the script is

```
find /NO/20171013 -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -w 655044810645 {} \; 2>/dev/null | /usr/bin/wc -l
LINES count is 0
In not found
find /NO/20171013 -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -w 734729751028 {} \; 2>/dev/null | /usr/bin/wc -l
LINES count is 0
In not found
```

Actually the `*.txt` files under `/NO/20171013` has files with pattern `655044810645` and `734729751028` .  Hence the `Word count` should not be 0 and it has to get into `else` part.

What could be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, set up a proper `$PATH` (and see answer by [Kamil Maciorowski](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/108618/kamil-maciorowski)):

Logg in with suitable user (root?) and execute:

```
echo PATH=$PATH
```

Add the output in the start of your script

**OR** you can add a full path to `find` command. If you don't know where `find` are placed, execute:

```
which find
```

Output will be like this: `/usr/bin/find`

**And you have a mistake inside loop**:

You need to replace single quotes with doublequotes (around of `${LINE}`), otherwise the variable will not be interpreted:

```
echo "find ${PATHS} -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -w "${LINE}" {} \; 2>/dev/null | wc -l"
LINES=`find ${PATHS} -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -w "${LINE}" {} \; 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
```

---

Some notes:

1. You do not need `cat file`, try to use loop instead. But use only `while`, not `for`! [Read Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: +1 Because you cover issues my answer doesn't (I decided not to duplicate them).

Comment: @Egor Vasilyev OKay I understand the usage of for and while now. But `find` command isn't returning any output. I even changed the single quotes to double quotes, even then the find isn't returning any output.

Comment: @sabarish jackson, can you update your answer with the latest script code?

Comment: @EgorVasilyev I have edited my question with output and edits in script. Please look into it.

Comment: @sabarish jackson, $PATH - is built-in shell variable. You need to use different variable name such as $PATH_TO_FOLDER or something else. See answer by Kamil Maciorowski

Comment: @EgorVasilyev YEah. FInally. That worked. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 6):

`$PATH` is [important variable with meaning](https://askubuntu.com/q/551990/693277). You should choose another name.

In this case `find` executable cannot be found because `$PATH` doesn't lead to it. You are not notified because of `2>/dev/null`.

`echo` is probably a shell builtin, it needs no `$PATH` to work. The same for `for` etc.

Comment: Okay. Now I changed the PATH to PATHS, even then it isn't working.
I am getting the below output.
`/NO/20171013/
655044810645 734729751028
find /NO/20171013/ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -w '655044810645' {} \; 2>/dev/null | /usr/bin/wc -l
0
LINES
0
find /NO/20171013/ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -w '734729751028' {} \; 2>/dev/null | /usr/bin/wc -l
0 
LINES
0 `

Comment: @steeldriver These backticks may be right. With `cat` they make the content of `STAT44.txt` be assigned to the variable.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski oops you are right - must remember not to post before coffee ;)